# Playback options with ffplay

Tags: m3u8

I don't know the following method in ffplay. If you know them, let me know.

1. I want to add header information to the m3u8 file.
   Additional information is required in the header to get the AES. How can I add this?
2. How to play video and audio simultaneously when they are separate.
   Video stream: https://aaa.com/video.m3u8
   Audio stream: https://aaa.com/audio.m3u8

Bests,

Answer (score 0):

> 1. I want to add header information to the m3u8 file. Additional information is required in the header to get the AES. How can I add
>    this?

[ffplay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffplay.html) is a media player and not a content authoring tool. So it does not support editing content.

> 2. How to play video and audio simultaneously when they are separate.
>    Video stream: https://aaa.com/video.m3u8 Audio stream:
>    https://aaa.com/audio.m3u8

You need to create an [HLS master playlist](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8216#section-8.6) that contains the video playlist as a variant stream and the audio playlist as a rendition, like so:

```
   #EXTM3U
   #EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="audio",NAME="English",DEFAULT=YES,AUTOSELECT=YES,LANGUAGE="en",URI="https://aaa.com/audio.m3u8"
   #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=7680000,CODECS="...",AUDIO="audio"
   https://aaa.com/video.m3u8
```